# How can I show/hide divs dynamically (on KeyUp, iTunes style) using Javascript/jQuery and a text or search field with case insensitive

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, html, dynamic

I set out on a journey to create an iTunes-like search using Javascript. I learned about jQuery, and with some help from people on StackOverflow, I was [successful](http://jsfiddle.net/DcYd2/).

I've come back here to share with you a very simple way to create a dynamic hide/show list based on the user input.

```
Let's search!
```

The entirety of the tutorial code can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/e8DXHWex).

And a JSFiddle for it is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mXUtv/)!

Comment: You have to make it case insensitive - search is not working properly

Comment: How so? It's a case sensitive search. How would I make it case insensitive? I'd prefer that.

Comment: ok - nevermind if thats what you wanted , but normally I (as a user) would think "app"  would pop up APPLE , but it doesn't - it returns nothing , "APP" does return APPLE

Comment: Ya, I'm on a schedule and progress = grade. But I still spent 1.5 weeks learning web languages just because I wanted to do this search. However, it seemed making it case insensitive would take too long (it's due in 2 weeks and we still have to connect it to the database, etc.). Do you happen to know how to do a case insensitive search?

Comment: This is a nice idea, but Stack Overflow is designed for a Q&A format. There's nothing wrong with answering your own question, though, and it's encouraged. I think you'd be fine if you just edited the question to look like an actual question: "I'm trying to do XYZ with jQuery, how can I get that to work?"

Comment: You can make it case insensitive by converting the search term into all lower or upper case, and doing the same for the items in the list. That way, it will be comparing uppercase to uppercase or lowercase to lowercase. :)

Comment: Now this is logically what I figured, but I don't seem to have the syntactic ingredients available. Since I've created this mini-tutorial I want to add it to this code with minimal changes. Any suggestions?

Comment: JS has a function (`string.toLowerCase();` or `string.toUpperCase();`). Apply that to the searched term when you're using the div:contains. (`str.toUpperCase()`) Of course, your div will also have to be uppercase, so you could either have another hidden div that's in full caps, or you can extract the div content, change it to uppercase, then compare it with the search term.

Comment: Basically, you can use the code found here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive/

Comment: MrXenotype you have provided me with the final missing piece to this. :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a simple Div Layout with some text in the divs and search bar above it.

```
    <div class="search_bar">
      <form><!--The Field from which to gather data-->
        <input id="searchfield" type="text" onclick="value=''" value="Case Sensitive Search">
      </form>
    </div>
    <!--Containers With Text-->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="container_of_hc">
        <div class="horizontal_containers">Cat</div>
        <div class="color">Black</div>
        <div class="color">White</div>
        <div class="color">Orange</div>
      </div>
      <div class="horizontal_containers">Dog</div>
      <div class="horizontal_containers">Rat</div>
      <div class="horizontal_containers">Zebra</div>
      <div class="horizontal_containers">Wolf</div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
      .container {
        width: 100%;
      }
      .horizontal_containers {
        height:10%;
        border: solid 3px #B30015;
        font-size: 45px;
        text-align: center;
      }
```

Second, you will make a script utilizing jQuery. Remember the title says this is a Dynamic Search, meaning (for us) we want to update the search with each key typed:

```
$("#searchfield").keyup(function() {
```

*Note: Need a [selector](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp) refresher?*

Then we will set a variable to the value in #searchfield:

```
  var str = $("#searchfield").val();  //get current value of id=searchfield
```

To ensure we show all the divs in our list when there is nothing in the searchfield we create an if statement based on the length of our new variable (str):

```
  if (str.length == 0) {
    //if searchfield is empty, show all
    $(".horizontal_containers").show();
  }
```

Last, we do the actual hiding of the divs if the length of str is not 0:

```
  else {
    //if input contains matching string, show div
    //if input does not contain matching string, hide div
    $("div:contains('" + str + "').horizontal_containers").show();
    $("div:not(:contains('" + str + "')).horizontal_containers").hide();
  }
});
```

The `div:contains()` and `div:not(:contains())` statements are what set the conditions. It's essentially an if statement. They search the text contained within the div, not the div attributes. If you want to search a deeper div structure you can use more than one selector in the script's jQuery statements like so:

```
if (str.length == 0) {
//if searchfield is empty, show all
  $(".container .color").show();
  } else {
    //if input contains matching string, show div
    //if input does not contain matching string, hide div
    $(".container div:contains('" + str + "').color").show();
    $(".container div:not(:contains('" + str + "')).color").hide();
  }
```

Replace the script statement you already have to give it a try.

*Note: The nesting structure of your divs must match that in your selector.*

And that's essentially it. If you have tips to improve this, know how to change it to a [case insensitive search](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive/), or anything else you can think of, please let me know!

***Thanks to MrXenoType I have learned case insensitivity for the :contains function.***

To create a case insensitive search for this project simply add:

```
$.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
    return function( elem ) {
        return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };
});
```

This creates a pseudo for the contains function. Place this code above your other script (within the same script) to make true for only this script.

Comment: Maybe make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so people can see what is actually happening?

Comment: With jsFiddle, you can separate your HTML/CSS/JS code and make it a lot easier to read: http://jsfiddle.net/8TNP9/

Answer (score 2):

So good to see Nick was successful on this experiment. good job on learning how to do it :)

Just in case you haven't encountered this jquery plugin, you might want to take a look at it too it's called Quick search.

https://github.com/riklomas/quicksearch

And I've used it on numerous pages and it works like a charm. example:
http://fedmich.com/works/types-of-project.htm

Comment: Thanks @fedmich :) I added it to my arsenal

Comment: ... and you dont always need to reinvent the wheel.
if theres already a plugin, use it whenever possible.
if it came from good source, and the script is mature enough, its probably been bug-tested quite a lot before.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$.expr[":"].contains_nocase = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
    return function( elem ) {
        return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };
});
```

for adding a :contains_nocase() selector with jQuery 1.8